# Probability of the events that will happen $X$ times in the next $Y$ minutes.

Tags: probability

> If an event happened at $a$, $b$ , $c$ , $d$ , $e$ .... minutes ago,
>   how to calculate the probability of the events that will happen $X$
>   times in the next $Y$ minutes?

Actually, I want to calculate the probability of the total number of corner in a soccer live match given some corners already happens.

Comment: It will just be $$\mathbb{P}(\text{events will happen X times in the next Y minutes}| \text{an event happened at a, b , c , d , e .... minutes ago})$$. Without any further assumptions you can't achieve anything

Comment: Can you improve your question by adding your thoughts and what you have tried?

Comment: This seems quate analogue to the process of radioactive decay. You may modell the time periods of your events as being exponentially destributed, i.e. the probabilit that the next event will take longer than x minutes is $\exp(-\frac{x}{\lambda})$, where $\lambda$ is some constant. The number of such event in a period $T$ is then Poisson-distributed. Now you may try to look for some ML estimate of parameters in question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mathematics SE. To be able to answer your question we would need some information on the distribution that is underlying this. Think about it this way: How would you go about estimating the amount of corners in that timeframe? Did you consider the binomial or poisson distribution? Why is this (not) a good fit?

Comment: @asdf: Probably you can "fake it" with Laplace's rule of succession or something similar?  Or make up a noninformative prior and use Bayes' theorem, I suppose.